# Jquery select value on submit for multiple dynamically generated selects

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, select

Trying to figure out if and how I can get the specific value by only using the class name.
Is it even possible?

All selects are generated dynamically and have the same class name. all the submit buttons have the same class name as well.

```
<div>
<select class="mystat" name="mystat" style="width: 140px">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">option 1</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="3">option 3</option>
</select>
<button class="go-btn" type="submit">Update</button>
</div>


$(document).on('click', '.go-btn', function(){
    var mystat = $('.mystat').val();
    alert('Value is ' + mystat);
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/20pu87ym/)

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: do you have a different submit per select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DOM navigation relative to `$(this)`.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.go-btn', function() {
  var mystat = $(this).siblings('.mystat').val();
  alert('Value is ' + mystat);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select class="mystat" name="mystat" style="width: 140px">
  <option value="1" selected="selected">option 1</option>
  <option value="2">option 2</option>
  <option value="3">option 3</option>
 </select>
  <button class="go-btn" type="submit">Update</button>
</div>
<div>
  <select class="mystat" name="mystat" style="width: 140px">
  <option value="1" selected="selected">option 1</option>
  <option value="2">option 2</option>
  <option value="3">option 3</option>
 </select>
  <button class="go-btn" type="submit">Update</button>
</div>
<div>
  <select class="mystat" name="mystat" style="width: 140px">
  <option value="1" selected="selected">option 1</option>
  <option value="2">option 2</option>
  <option value="3">option 3</option>
 </select>
  <button class="go-btn" type="submit">Update</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, because select tag is in the front of the button in each block

var mystat = $(this).prev().val();